# Flash-position of small circle keep changing when i click "Resume"

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to make small circles moving inside a big circle and also having buttons to pause,resume and reverse it. But when i pause and resume it, it will change the small circle's position but i want it to stay at the original position. Is there anyway to do it? and also is there a way to make reverse the direction when i click?(eg. starting is cw when i click "reverse" it will turn anti-cw and when i click "reverse" again it will go cw)

This is my code for action layer:

```
var Rec:Number=1;

stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);
function EntFrame(e:Event):void
{
if (Rec >= 1)
{
    CircleL.rotation-= 2;
}
else if(Rec <= -1)
{
    CircleL.rotation+=2;
}
}

var twoPI = 2 * Math.PI;
var circleSNum1:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum2:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum3:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum4:Number = Math.random();
var circleSNum5:Number = Math.random();
function randomRange(minNum:Number, maxNum:Number):Number 
{
return (Math.floor(Math.random() * (maxNum - minNum + 1)) + minNum);
}


var radius = randomRange(10, 90);

function move(event:Event):void{


CircleL.CircleS1.x = Math.cos(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;
CircleL.CircleS1.y = Math.sin(circleSNum1 * twoPI) * radius;

CircleL.CircleS2.x = Math.cos(circleSNum2 * twoPI) * radius;
CircleL.CircleS2.y = Math.sin(circleSNum2 * twoPI) * radius;

CircleL.CircleS3.x = Math.cos(circleSNum3 * twoPI) * radius;
CircleL.CircleS3.y = Math.sin(circleSNum3 * twoPI) * radius;

CircleL.CircleS4.x = Math.cos(circleSNum4 * twoPI) * radius;
CircleL.CircleS4.y = Math.sin(circleSNum4 * twoPI) * radius;

CircleL.CircleS5.x = Math.cos(circleSNum5 * twoPI) * radius;
CircleL.CircleS5.y = Math.sin(circleSNum5 * twoPI) * radius;
}
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,move);

Pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPause);
function clickPause(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Pause");
Rec=0
}

Resume.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickResume);
function clickResume(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Resume");
Rec=1
}

Reverse.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickReverse);
function clickReverse(Event:MouseEvent):void{
gotoAndStop("Reverse");
Rec=-1
}
```

[When i test it is this position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n33X6.png)

[After i click "pause" and "resume" the position of small circle changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLs6n.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the Enter Frame event listener when you want to pause and add it back when you need to resume. The enter frame event still triggers even if you call stop(); (gotoAndStop in this case). So the circle still moves even if you can't see it because you've jumped to another frame. When you come back to it (resume) it will look like it moved but it has never stopped.

```
Pause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickPause);
function clickPause(Event:MouseEvent):void{
//remove event listener 
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);
gotoAndStop("Pause");
Rec=0
}

Resume.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickResume);
function clickResume(Event:MouseEvent):void{
//add event listener 
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,EntFrame);
gotoAndStop("Resume");
Rec=1
}
```

Also, try writing your ActionScript in external files and remove it from the time line, also use classes...it's not that hard and will make you a better developer in the end.